# Symplectically embedding 2-spheres in 6-manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, spheres

There is a wealth of research that I have found that characterize different classes of compact $4$-manifolds by the ability (or lack thereof, in the case of aspherical) to (symplectically or smoothly) embed spheres of certain self-intersections into them.

However, I am interested in what I can learn about those **compact 6-manifolds** which admit symplectic or smooth embeddings of spheres or tori into them.  To be clear, I am only wishing to embed **surfaces** into compact six-manifolds... **not** spheres or tori of higher dimension.  Does anybody here know a nice source of collected research on this topic?  So far, I have not found it.  I think the most energy over the last $35$ years has been spent on $4$-manifolds.

Comment: To be clear, there is plenty of research, including the standard Whitney Embedding theorem, that describes the situation of smoothly embedding spheres in Euclidean spaces.... but I am interested in embeddings into compact manifolds.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but isn't this precisely the genus 0 case of Gromov-Witten theory? To my understand there is intense interest in this, especially in the case of Calabi-Yau 3-folds.

Comment: @MikeMiller You might be right.  I am not versed in Gromov-Witten theory, but thanks for the tip.